# Circle in which side of square is given

Tags: circles

[image]

I am not Able to proceed with this question .

Comment: A great way to approach these kinds of questions is to list what you know. What information does the diagram give you? Next time, please include this information in your question itself

Answer (score 1):

how can PQ be independent of a?
I am getting .6  a[image]

Comment: I get the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I get that
the length of "?"
is 3a/5.

This is probably the
longest possible way,
so here goes.

Let the two points
on the left and right ends
of the line labled "?"
be P and Q.

Put the origin at the base of the circle
near "a".

Let
$\angle DAP = \angle ADQ
=g$,
and let
$\sin g = s,
\cos g = c,
\tan g = t
$.

The equation of
$AP$ is 
$y = t(a/2-x)
$
and
the equation of
$BQ$ is 
$y = t(x+a/2)
$.

These intersect when
$x = 0$
at $(0, at/2)$.
This is
the center of the circle.
Call this $R$.

The distance $AP = a$,
and

$\begin{array}\\
AR^2
&=(a/2)^2+(ta/2)^2\\
&=(a/2)^2(1+t^2)\\
&=(a/2)^2(1+(s/c)^2)\\
&=(a/2)^2(1/c)^2\\
\text{so}\\
AR
&=a/(2c)
\end{array}
$

Therefore the radius
of the circle is
$a-a/(2c)
=a(1-1/(2c))
$.

But this has to be
$at/2$,
so
$at/2
=a(1-1/(2c))
$
or
$t
=2-1/c
$
or
$s/c = 2-1/c$
or
$s = 2c-1$.

Squaring,
$4c^2-4c+1
=s^2
=1-c^2
$,
so
$5c^2 = 4c$
so
$c = 0$
or
$c = 4/5$.

From this,
$s = \sqrt{1-16/25}
=3/5$,
and,
indeed,
$s = 2c-1$.

Also,
$t = s/c = 3/4$.

If point $P$
is at
$(-u, v)$,
then
$(u+a/2)^2+v^2 = a^2
$
and
$v/(u+a/2)
=t$
or
$v = t(u+a/2)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
a^2
&=(u+a/2)^2+t(u+a/2)^2 \\
&=(u+a/2)^2(1+t^2)\\
&=(u+a/2)^2(1/c^2)\\
\text{so}\\
ac
&=u+a/2\\
\text{or}\\
u
&=a(c-1/2)\\
&=3a/10\\
\end{array}
$

Finally,
the length of $?$ is
$2u = 6a/10
=3a/5
$.